# Is there a simple generic solution to the following integral

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I have the following integral:
$$ I(k) = \int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} f(g(x)) g'(x) \exp\left(j k x\right) dx. $$

Is there a generic way to solve this integral? If not, I can start expanding the functions in the question.

Here, $j = \sqrt{-1}$.

P.S.: The expansion of these functions are genuinely daunting.

Comment: What is $\dfrac{g(x)}{dx}$? That is some serious abuse of notation.

Comment: It is the derivative of $g(x)$. I should edit it to $g^{'}(x)$

Comment: @CfourPiO. It's enough with `g'(x)`. Using `g^{'}(x)` raises the prime sign more than necessary.

Comment: If $f(y) = F’(y)$ for some anti derivative $F$, then $f(g(x))g’(x)$ can be written as simply $F’(x)$. See if this helps!